# Finding median in unsorted array

Tags: java

I need to take input such as 4 1 6 5 0. The 4 determines how big the array is, and the rest are array elements. The catch is I can't sort it first. I'm at a loss of how to begin.

Comment: Is the input a String?

Comment: I'm fine on how to take the input and add it to an array. I just don't have any idea of how to do this without sorting it

Comment: Here's what you need to start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm Good luck.

Comment: Why can't you sort it?  It's really the only sensible way to do it.

Comment: Is this the usual homework thing, where you're not allowed to use any of the methods in Collections API etc....?

Comment: This is exactly my problem haha.

Comment: Are you allowed to create your own sorting method?

Comment: Are you allowed to build your own frequency table?

Comment: What @Shashank said. E.g. quickselect.

Comment: @DavidWallace Well that's not entirely true. I think the intention is to point people towards selection algorithms, frequency tables etc.

Comment: The answer for my input above is 3.

Answer (score 1):

There Is A Chapter In MIT's Introduction To Algorithm Course (http://www.catonmat.net/blog/mit-introduction-to-algorithms-part-four) Dedicated To Order Statics. You Can Find The Median In O(N) Expected Time, O(N^2) Worst Case.

Comment: You mean median. Pun intended.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you should use sorted list, it uses a perform any algorithm to sort the list. So you can sort them first and then get the n/2 element, it's your median.